# rails-settings get all settings for a key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have [ledermann-rails-settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) in my project which is used to store settings. I want to get all settings values for a key. My model is like

```
class Prescription < ActiveRecord:Base 
  has_settings do |s|
    s.key :print_options ,:defaults=> {:medication=>true,:medical_history=>false}   
  end
end
```

I have gone through the [documention](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ledermann-rails-settings/1.2.0/frames) on rubydoc and also on [git](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) but couldn't find a method to fetch all values in one go. There is `all` method available for setting object but it did not work in my case. If I do `Prescription.last.settings(:print_options).all` It returns `nil` which is because it thinks `all` as a key and tries to fetch value for it.

I have seen the object structure and saw the values stored in `value` attribute of setting object, which can be fetched like

```
Prescription.last.settings(:print_options).value
```

but the problem with this is that it do not return default values whereas I need to get all values(including defaults). If someone know any method for this purpose or can correct me on using `all` method then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Prescription#to_settings_hash`](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings/blob/master/lib/rails-settings/base.rb#L38) is probably what you are looking for:

```
Prescription.last.to_settings_hash
```

Comment: yeah! I also found this method while checking base.rb in the source code. I can do `Prescription.last.to_settings_hash[:print_options]` to get my required hash.